# Javascript doesn't work on Chrome and Firefox, but works on IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have this line of code that works on IE

Javascript:

```
function getInfo() {
    var date = new Date(date);
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var test = "print";
    document.getElementById('lol').value = month;
}
```

Body:

```
<input type=text name=lol>
<input type=button onClick=getInfo() value=lol>
```

It works on IE, but not on Chrome and Firefox. Does Chrome and Firefox has a different Javascript?

Comment: Did you try adding `id='lol'` to your `input`? The script selects element by ID and if I am not wrong IE does take the `name` also into consideration while the others don't.

Comment: You have no element with an `id` of `lol`, so I don't see how this works in *any* browser.

Comment: I'm sorry, but using name=lol in IE works perfectly well

Comment: @StellaMarisChua that says more about IE's incredibly poor standards compliance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx - IE docs for getElementById - note that it searches both name AND id

Answer (score 3):

`getElementById` is for looking up elements **by `id`**. Your input doesn't have an `id`, it just has a `name`. Your code works on IE because (some versions of) IE [are confused](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html) and return elements with `name` attributes from `getElementById`. This is a bug in IE.

To correct the problem, either add `id="lol"` to your input:

```
<input type=text name=lol id=lol>
<input type=button onClick=getInfo() value=lol>
```

...or use `querySelector("[name=lol]")`:

```
document.querySelector('[name=lol]').value = month;
```

`querySelector` returns the first element it can find that matches the given CSS selector. It's available on all modern browsers, and IE8.

Separately: Your code is passing `undefined` into the `Date` constructor, here:

```
var date = new Date(date);
```

...because that code is, in effect:

```
var date;
date = new Date(date);
```

...and variables start out with the value `undefined`.

On a browser with a standards-compliant JavaScript engine, you'll end up with an invalid date, because the specification requires that the engine convert the argument to a number and then use that as the underyling "time value" (milliseconds-since-the-epoch). Converting `undefined` to a number results in `NaN` ("not a number"); dates using  `NaN` as their "time value" are called invalid dates. Using `getMonth` and similar on them returns `NaN`.

If you want the current date, just don't use the argument at all:

```
var date = new Date();
```

---

Here's a working version of your code (with minimal modifications) using an `id` and not passing `undefined` into `Date`:

```js
function getInfo() {
    var date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var test = "print";
    document.getElementById('lol').value = month;
}
```

```html
<input type=text name=lol id=lol>
<input type=button onClick=getInfo() value=lol>
```

And here's one using `querySelector` with the `name`:

```js
function getInfo() {
    var date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var test = "print";
    document.querySelector('[name=lol]').value = month;
}
```

```html
<input type=text name=lol>
<input type=button onClick=getInfo() value=lol>
```

---

Side note: I really would put the content of your `onClick` attribute in quotes, because it contains non-alphanumeric characters. According to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0), your markup *should* work, and does on Chrome (the unquoted syntax allows anything but spaces, `"`, `'`, `<`, `>`, and `` ` ``), but...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Yeah, I was making the minimum necessary changes, and you don't technically *have* to put those in quotes.

Comment: Consistency... You say he shouldn't do something and then you do it right away. Kinda ironic. It's just to keep consistency on your code.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Yeah, I was just editing to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use Jquery

```
<input type=text id="somethingElse">
<input type=button id="something">


$( "#something" ).click(function() {
    var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;
    $( "#somethingElse" ).val(currentMonth);
});
```

Comment: jQuery maybe useful for a lot of stuff but I fail to see why jQuery is required for such a simple item.

Comment: See things like document.getElementById hurts my eyes and also for example jQuery elements display even when JavaScript is disabled

Comment: reminds me of [this](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) :)

Answer (score -1):

You're missing quotes and also the `id`:

```
<input type="text" id="lol" name="lol">
<input type="button" onClick="getInfo();" value="lol">
```